# MMO Server-Game Sockets, Security and Usage

Tags: c#, sockets, security, send

I'm working on a Socket MMO Server-Game project and I want to ask something:

- I'll send some data with Tcp socket. Can anybody chance this socket data from outside? Namely I called socket.send() and I'll send "abc" data. Can anybody make it "dsf"?
- I'll use this project in a MMO game project. Now, I think I need 2 type of sockets. First socket connection secured with SSL Stream; second one is unsecured, classical Tcp socket (there isn't any crypt/decrypt process. network packets can be read easilly). I'll use normal Tcp socket for sending positions and messaging like fast-unimportant datas. If I want to send some important data like login-room request I'll use secured (SSL) socket connection. Is that true way to manage a MMO Server-Game system?

Comment: The first rule when creating a networked games is: Never trust the client.

Comment: Also, most MMOs uses UDP sockets for the main game events, and TCP for things like chat.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ok, I'll use UDP for positioning and TCP for messaging. Other TCP socket is secured with SSL. But can client make a cheath and can change self socket data? Can client teleport? What can we do about this?

Comment: You have to do all calcul on the server as well. If a client sends that the PC is walking with a speed of 500 km/h then you obviously know something is wrong. Also since the server knows where each PC (and NPC) is, getting a message from a client saying something else is also easy to detect. Basically, you have to keep two copies of all data and do all calculations twice, once on the client and once on the server.

Comment: Keep in mind that network spikes may seem like cheat attempts in some cases, ie. the player would appear to be frozen and then move quickly (I bet you have observed this in a game or two). I would focus on creating a fun game first, though.